# Show enter contents of JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

QUESTION ::

I know this is a redundant question, but I am finding little help in other similar questions...

I have a json file.

I can load the json fine, but when I try to output a specific element with this

```
div.innerHTML = jsonfromfile[element];
```

I only get this...

```
[object Object]
```

as my output...

How do I get the entire element to display instead of this [object Object]?

more code to get a feel for how it is being done up...

```
var activity;
function jsfr() {
    $.getJSON('myjson.json', function(response){
    jsonfromfile = response;
    })  
}
```

.

.

.

SOLUTION :: from Francis Stalin's answer

I added a new function...

```
        var items;
    function outty(data) {

            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                items=items+key+","+val+";";
            });
    }
```

and i set the depth on the json leaving me with an object which i send to outty...

```
    dpth = jsonfromfile["elementOne"]["elSubone"]["elsuboneSub"];
    outty(dpth);
    div.innerHTML=items;
```

here's the HTML that shows the div it all prints to...

```
    <div class="col-rght">
        <div class="text" id="postcomp"></div>
    </div> <!--div class="col-rght"-->
```

this turns the object of your desired json depth into an ugly string that you can then format for display..

if you like html lists check out how Stalin did it, but be weary of his appendTo('div')... this will place your list in every div.  Try putting the name of the class of the div you want to print to with a period leading it, appendTo('.outputbox')

Comment: `[object Object]` is the default string representation of objects. You can convert the object back to JSON and show it.

Comment: how would I convert it back to json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't append the json object directly into ur html. u have to parse and convert into string

```
$.getJSON('myjson.json', function(data) {
var items = [];
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
});
$('<ul/>', {
'class': 'my-new-list',
html: items.join('')
}).appendTo('div');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: but I only want to display certain elements and their subordinates as specified by user input.  does the .each() function have to be inside the getJSON() function?

Comment: i put it in as is, but still displaying nothing

Comment: excellent, finally did some maneuvering and got it working.  Thanks for your help and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify(yourjsonobjecthere)`

Comment: with this there is nothing placed into the div?

Comment: I gave you the format for getting a readable representation in general. In this case, you'd want to do `div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(jsonfromfile[element])`

Comment: yeah your fiddle works, and there seems no obvious difference in my implementation, yet still displaying a blank

Comment: ah, if i place my json into your fiddle all works well... clearly this is a getJSON issue

Answer (score 0):

Try `div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(jsonfromfile[element]);`

Comment: with this there is nothing placed into the div?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(jsonfromfile[element])` will return a string. Are you sure `div` points to a DOM element? If `div` is a jQuery object, use `div[0]`

Comment: I know the div is functioning fine.  also the json is working if I go all the way through a series subordinate elements and ask for a value of that element, but i want to print all of the elements and their subordinates and their values